# System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'libuv' when publishing .NET Core Website on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, libuv

I'm getting an error when publishing my .NET Core Asp.NET Web Application on a Windows Server 2008 R2. It has to do with **libuv**:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'libuv': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.Libuv.NativeMethods.uv_loop_size()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.Libuv.loop_size()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvLoopHandle.Init(Libuv uv)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.KestrelThread.ThreadStart(Object parameter)
```

The strange thing is, when I publish locally on my development machine, I can see the **libuv.dll** in the publish folder. And the application works on my local machine through IIS.

**project.json framework:**

```
"frameworks": {
  "net461": {}
},
```

**Using these commands:**

```
dotnet restore
dotnet build
dotnet publish --configuration Release  --runtime active
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: are you using final version of asp.net-core? Seams like this issue was fixed in RC2 release - https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/627

Comment: The problem with this question is the title declares it is for core but the project.json file reveals otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

I found the reason for this error, at least what was causing it in my case now, 10 months later.

I had an older web-api project created with .net core 1.1 and found in the `*.csproj` file this `PropertyGroup`:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net47</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

In a newer project that I created a few day ago but with the newer template and .NET Core 2.0 it looked like this:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net47</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Here the `RuntimeIdentifier` was missing. I added it to the new project and the error disappeared. Now the server starts as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I solve this removing this strings from csproj

```
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net461'">
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
  </ItemGroup>
```